# How to exclude template in Helm

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm

I want Helm to avoid generating yaml files from hpa templates.How can i do this?

If use something like this in hpa.yml:

```
{{- if .Values.hpaEnabled }}
 kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
 apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
{{ end }}
```

And in values.yml:

```
hpaEnabled: false
```

Then Helm just deleting hpa from OpenShift cluster.

Comment: The usual workaround is this, or delete this template if it's not needed anywhere

Comment: Which OpenShift version are you using? Could you please add example helm chart that you are using? Please make your [issue reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The `{{ if }}` block you have is equivalent to deleting the template file, if `hpaEnabled` is false.  If `helm install` had previously installed an HPA, and you disable it with a setting and `helm upgrade`, then it's normal for Helm to delete the object it had previously installed.  Which object is actually getting deleted?  When you say you don't want Helm to generate YAML files, do you want anything more than Helm not installing a new HPA?